# Android sending a http request every minute to server? repeating a task?

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, timertask

I want to send a request to the server every minute, Basically I have method and needs to be run every min to send to server some query. what is the best way of doing this? I have searched on the internet and couldnt find a straight forward solution to this. I tried to use timer and timertask classes but it didnt work. I also found something about AlarmManager people say AlarmManager is the best way of doing this but I dont know how? could you direct me a sample application or if it is easy could you send me a sample code here. also I look forward to your opinion about this.

Thank you

Comment: If you found a solution please share it with us, man

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) facility

Comment: Could you give me a bit more details? I have a service already but I dont know how I can implement a service to send a request every minute. Is there any example of this? Thank you.

Comment: What didnt work about the `Timer` class? `Timer` task in a `Service` using `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` would be my first thought.

Comment: I will get crazy soon :) timer =new Timer();
       
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     
    }
          
         }, 5000, 5000);  This is a code inside my service. I also have a broadcastreceiver and running this service from the broadcastreciver and I also have receiver and service in the manifest file. What am I missing here. why it is so hard to see somthing is running in a loop every N min ?